# Grouping/sorting with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've got this list with student grades:

| Grade | Student |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | John |
| 10 | Mary |
| 9 | Peter |
| 9 | Allison |

And I want to group them like this:

| Grade | Students |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | John, Mary |
| 9 | Peter, Allison |

So I got this Linq command:

```
var gradesAndStudents = studentsGrades.GroupBy(p => p.grade, p => p.student,
    (key, g) => new { Grade = key, Students = g.ToList() });
```

So now the result is grouped and sorted and the Grade shows all students with their grades:

| Grade | Students |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 10, John |
|  | 10, Mary |
| 9 | 9, Peter |
|  | 9, Allison |

But how do I get the students name only as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var gradesAndStudents = from p in studentsGrades
              group p.student by p.grade into g
              select new { Grade= g.Key, Students =string.Join(", ", g.ToList()) };
```

Comment: Hi feras, It would be even better if you could add the sorting too : 
var gradesAndStudents = from p in studentsGrades
              orderby p.Brands 
              group p.student by p.grade into g
              select new { Grade= g.Key, Students =string.Join(", ", g.ToList()) };

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this:

```
var gradesAndStudents = studentsGrades
   .GroupBy(p => p.grade, p => p.student, 
           (key, g) => new { Grade = key, Students = string.Join(", ", g.ToList()) });
```

Once you have your list of student names, you can join them with `string.Join`

Comment: Hi Nateous, This didn't work for me, I still got each garde/student separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var studentsByGrades = studentGrades.GroupBy(sg => sg.Grade).Select(sg => KeyValuePair.Create(sg.Key, sg.Select(s => s.Name))).ToList();
```

In this case, `studentsByGrades` will be a list of key-value pairs with a key the `grade` and the value list of student names from that grade i.e. a list of strings. Or you can try something like this

```
 var studentsByGrades = studentGrades.GroupBy(sg => sg.Grade).ToDictionary(sg => sg.Key, sg => sg.Select(s => s.Name));
```

in the second example, `studentsByGrades` will be a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary will be the grades and the values will be a lists with the student names from that grade.

Comment: Hi Aton, This didn't work for me, the first method gives an error about the KayValuePair, needs 2 type arguments
The second method  I got each grade seperate, but the students also, so not in one string.